# Columns aligning crooked

Tags: python, formatting

I am trying to align variables in columns. I want them to be left-aligned in each column. However, when I align the inputs, I think that it aligns it based on the length of the characters. The issue is that the inputs vary from use to use, so I cannot just hard code in the spaces to align them. Not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

I have tried reading a bunch of other posts, but I cannot figure out how to properly format the alignment, even when I get their code suggestions correct. Also, I am using Trinket.io, if that makes a difference.

```
a1 = input("Enter Item 1: ")
monthly1 = float(input("Enter " + a1 + " Monthly Amount: $"))
b1 = ("$%.2f" % (monthly1))
yearly1 = float(monthly1*12)
c1 = ("$%.2f" % (yearly1))
a2 = input("Enter Item 2: ")
monthly2 = float(input("Enter " + a2 + " Monthly Amount: $"))
b2 = ("$%.2f" % (monthly2))
yearly2 = float(monthly1*12)
c2 = ("$%.2f" % (yearly2))

print "==============================="
print ("%-20s %-10s %-10s" % (a1, b1, c1))
print ("%-20s %-10s %-10s" % (a2, b2, c2))
```

[Screenshot in Trinket.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bckBk.png)

Copy-Paste Output:

```
Enter Item 1:  Rent
Enter Rent Monthly Amount: $ 750
Enter Item 2:  Gas
Enter Gas Monthly Amount: $ 50
===============================
 Rent                 $750.00    $9000.00 
 Gas                  $50.00     $600.00
```

Comment: Aren't all those already _left_ aligned like you asked? The leftmost character of each value is in the same column.

Comment: How is this "crooked"? (Using using `Trinket.io` is relevant in the sense that some of the nicest modules for pretty-printing tables are not standard library modules and `Trinket.io` doesn't play nice with tools like `pip`.)

Comment: @MatsLindh
I agree with you guys that it looks properly aligned pasted here. It is for a class and we have to take a screenshot and submit it, but it will not seem to properly line up on Trinket.io. Please refer to the image for crooked alignment. I should have included that initially. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: That's because you (or trinket.io) are using a font that's not monospaced. Getting stuff aligned in that case is far harder, and requires knowledge of the font used. Switch to a monospaced font.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking maybe you want the dollar amounts to be *right* aligned. So changing your prints to:

```
print ("%-20s %10s %10s" % (a1, b1, c1))
print ("%-20s %10s %10s" % (a2, b2, c2))
```

I get:

```
Enter Item 1: Rent
Enter Rent Monthly Amount: $750
Enter Item 2: Gas
Enter Gas Monthly Amount: $50
===============================
Rent                    $750.00   $9000.00
Gas                      $50.00    $600.00
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: Your advice is sound, but unfortunately I did not include the screenshot in my original post. The issue is that it is crooked in Trinket.io when I run the code. I edited the post to include the image if you are still curious.